# Restrict callers of method to a class

Tags: kotlin, annotations

In Kotlin, I frequently come across the following pattern:

```
class DlgManager {
   fun dismiss(dlg: Dialogue) {
      // ...
      dlg.onDismiss()
      // ...
   }
}
class Dialogue {
   // Never call this directly, always go through DlgManager!
   fun onDismiss() {
      // ...
   }
}
```

I would like to make it impossible for arbitrary callers to call `onDismiss` except if the caller is `DlgManager`. Is this possible with an annotation?

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class RestrictCallers(val caller: KClass<out Any>)

class DlgManager {
   fun dismiss(dlg: Dialogue) {
      // ...
      dlg.onDismiss()
      // ..
   }
}
class Dialogue {
   @RestrictCallers(DlgManager::class)
   fun onDismiss() {
      // ...
   }
}
```

How would such an implementation of @RestrictCallers look like?

Comment: I would say just give up. Just write that in the documentation - when something breaks because someone called this from elsewhere, it is their own fault for not following the rules. Or, rethink your design so you don't need to do this in the first place. If you really want to go down the annotation route, you'd need to write an IntelliJ (or whatever IDE you're using) plugin. But again, this can be easily bypassed by not installing that plugin.

Comment: That is to say, this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do precisely what you want to do would require going outside normal language rules and writing a compiler plugin.

##### Opt-in annotations

However you can get pretty close using an [opt-in annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/opt-in-requirements.html) if you don't mind annotating acceptable callers as well.

To do this, define your opt-in annotation:

```
@RequiresOptIn(message = "Only to be called by annotated callers")
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class RestrictOnDismissCallers
```

Annotate `onDismiss`:

```
class Dialogue {
   @RestrictOnDismissCallers
   fun onDismiss() {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Then an error will be generated by any function trying to call `onDismiss` except for those annotated with the opt-in annotation, such as:

```
@OptIn(RestrictOnDismissCallers::class)
fun dismiss(dlg: Dialogue)
```

Answer (score 3):

It highly depends on a specific case, but if some operation is considered internal, then ideally, we shouldn't expose it in the first place. We can create separate types for the user of the API and for the internal processing, then cast them if needed:

```kotlin
class DlgManager {
    fun dismiss(dlg: Dialogue) {
        if (dlg !is DismissableDialogue) error("unknown dialogue type")
        dlg.onDismiss()
        // ...
    }

    fun getDialog(): Dialogue = DismissableDialogue()
}

interface Dialogue {
    fun foo()
}

private class DismissableDialogue : Dialogue {
    fun onDismiss() {}
    ...
}
```

The user of the dialogue API doesn't even know about the `DismissableDialogue` type and its `onDismiss` function. Assuming the `DlgManager` is the only way to create/acquire dialogs, we can even make sure all dialogs are of the `DismissableDialogue` type, so `dismiss` doesn't have to check, but simply cast to it - then this solution is 100% reliable.

You could also consider not passing the dialogue to the manager to run its `onDismiss`, but actually do the opposite: we call the `dialogue.dismiss()` and internally it calls the associated manager. It feels a cleaner OOP to me, and then your problem ceases to exist. But that depends if the dialogue could be considered a "managed object", so it knows its manager.